# UI Design with Data Visualization

Tags: interface-design, data-visualisation

recently I got an invite to join a company that works with data. They asked me for designing different Data Visualization, but unfortunately, I don't have experience designing data. In my past, I just designed some small dashboard for small projects.

My question is:
Designing data visualization should I use real-data, or can I just make only inputs that show how the data should look and how should I communicate with the developer?

Comment: What type of data? Can you _get_ real data? Does it really matter? How can we help provide an answer to you?

Comment: Real data is easy to get. For example meteorological data is plentiful, and because of its cyclic nature its easy to rediscover fourier transform by mistake with it. If you dont work with real data then your not doing any contemplation on the nature of the data. Oftentimes your visualisation is subtly wrong for the real data.

Comment: A graphic artist who hasn't a slightest idea of what math relations inside that data need to be visualized can have a too big challenge. He needs an engineer or scientist to tell the visualization idea and calculate the needed numbers and their possible class borders. You make it look good and he makes sure you show the right things.

Comment: how are you going to do data visualization design if you don't use real data?